# iOS quartz drawing app

Tags: ios, drawing

Update: Correct draw rect method shown below

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if(layer == nil)
    {
        float scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width *scale, rect.size.height *scale);
        layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
        layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
        CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, scale, scale);
        viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    }

    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = path.bezierPath;
    CGContextAddPath(layerContext, bezierPath.CGPath);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(layerContext, path.width);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(layerContext, path.color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineCap(layerContext, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextStrokePath(layerContext);

    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, viewRect, layer);
    self.empty = NO;
}
```

Update:  I have done as suggested, added paths to an array and drawn to a CGLayer as below.  However, when lots of paths are drawn, performance does slow.  Have I made any mistakes?

```
    - (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    CGPoint velocity = [pan velocityInView:self];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentPoint;
    currentPoint = [pan locationInView:self];

    float velocityMagnitude = sqrtf(velocity.x * velocity.x + velocity.y * velocity.y);

    float clampedVelocityMagnitude = clamp(VELOCITY_CLAMP_MIN, VELOCITY_CLAMP_MAX, velocityMagnitude);
    float normalizedVelocity = (clampedVelocityMagnitude - VELOCITY_CLAMP_MIN) / (VELOCITY_CLAMP_MAX - VELOCITY_CLAMP_MIN);

    float lowPassFilterAlpha = STROKE_WIDTH_SMOOTHING;
    float newThickness = (STROKE_WIDTH_MAX - STROKE_WIDTH_MIN) * normalizedVelocity + STROKE_WIDTH_MIN;
    self.lineWidth = self.lineWidth * lowPassFilterAlpha + newThickness * (1 - lowPassFilterAlpha);

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);
    CGMutablePathRef subpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(subpath, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(subpath);

    Path *path = [[Path alloc] init];
    path.width = self.lineWidth;
    path.color = [UIColor redColor];
    path.bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:subpath];
    [pathArray addObject:path];
    CGPathRelease(subpath);

    CGRect drawBox = bounds;
    drawBox.origin.x -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
    drawBox.origin.y -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
    drawBox.size.width += self.lineWidth * 4.0;
    drawBox.size.height += self.lineWidth * 4.0;

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];

    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded | pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
        self.lineWidth = STROKE_WIDTH_MIN;
    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.backgroundColor set];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if(layer == nil)
    {
        float scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width * scale, rect.size.height * scale);
        layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
        layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < [pathArray count]; i++)
    {
        Path *path = [pathArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIBezierPath *bezierPath = path.bezierPath;
        CGContextAddPath(layerContext, bezierPath.CGPath);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(layerContext, path.width);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(layerContext, path.color.CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineCap(layerContext, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextStrokePath(layerContext);
    }

    CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointZero, layer);

    self.empty = NO;
}
```

I'm using the code below to draw lines with variable widths according to the velocity of the user's pan gesture.  It works fine but when I draw near to or over a line that has been drawn before, its line width changes to match the velocity of the current gesture and line.  How can I ensure that drawn lines maintain the thickness they were originally drawn at please?

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    CGPoint velocity = [pan velocityInView:self];

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentPoint;
    currentPoint = [pan locationInView:self];

    float velocityMagnitude = sqrtf(velocity.x * velocity.x + velocity.y * velocity.y);

    float clampedVelocityMagnitude = clamp(VELOCITY_CLAMP_MIN, VELOCITY_CLAMP_MAX, velocityMagnitude);
    float normalizedVelocity = (clampedVelocityMagnitude - VELOCITY_CLAMP_MIN) / (VELOCITY_CLAMP_MAX - VELOCITY_CLAMP_MIN);

    float lowPassFilterAlpha = STROKE_WIDTH_SMOOTHING;
    float newThickness = (STROKE_WIDTH_MAX - STROKE_WIDTH_MIN) * normalizedVelocity + STROKE_WIDTH_MIN;
    self.lineWidth = self.lineWidth * lowPassFilterAlpha + newThickness * (1 - lowPassFilterAlpha);

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);
    CGMutablePathRef subpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(subpath, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(subpath, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(subpath);

    CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, subpath);
    CGPathRelease(subpath);

    CGRect drawBox = bounds;
    drawBox.origin.x -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
    drawBox.origin.y -= self.lineWidth * 2.0;
    drawBox.size.width += self.lineWidth * 4.0;
    drawBox.size.height += self.lineWidth * 4.0;

    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded | pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
        self.lineWidth = STROKE_WIDTH_MIN;
    }
    else
    {
         [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];
    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.backgroundColor set];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    self.empty = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the line width changes you need to start a new path. You need to store all of these paths into an array (or similar) and draw each of them when `drawRect:` is called. This will maintain the line widths at the time of drawing.

What is currently happening is that you are always drawing a single path, so you're always resetting the line width for the whole path. It's just that you're the view to only refresh `drawBox` so that is the only bit that you actually see get updated.

The performance will be bad as you add more lines, so you'll probably want to start looking at using a `CGLayer` to cache the previously drawn paths and render the layer into the context in `drawRect:` instead of iterating the paths.

Comment: Please see my question updated with further progress.  Does this look correct? Thanks

Comment: In drawrect, the idea is to draw the layer and the 'current' path, not all paths. The layer should contain, prerendered, all of the 'saved' paths.

Comment: Thanks Wain, appreciated